# A question of Quantitative aptitude and Logic in School Level

Tags: algebra-precalculus, volume

I need help in a question asked by my younger brother in his aptitude exam of Secondary level.

Question's Image ->[image]

> I thought answer should be B

> Answer is given (A)

I can't reason how it must be independent of both d and n.

Can anyone please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the balls fill the cylinder snugly and from end to end, the cylinder must have an internal diameter of $d$ and height of $nd$, so its volume is

$$\pi\left(\frac{d}2\right)^2\cdot nd=\frac{\pi nd^3}4\;.$$

The total volume of the balls is

$$n\cdot\frac43\pi\left(\frac{d}2\right)^3=\frac{\pi nd^3}6\;.$$

The volume **fraction** occupied by the melted balls is therefore

$$\frac{\frac{\pi nd^3}6}{\frac{\pi nd^3}4}=\frac23\;,$$

which is independent of both $n$ and $d$.

One can arrive at this conclusion without actually doing the calculations by realizing that both the internal volume of the cylinder and the total volume of wax are proportional to $nd^3$, so the volume fraction of the melted wax is just the ratio of the proportionality constants.

Comment: Hi Brian, I have bit of a semantics question: for example, if the temperature $T$ in a room *depends* on your position $x$ in the room why can we write $T=f(x)$ for some function $f$? I think i'm just trying to conceptualize translating the english to the mathematical formulation; thanks for your time!

Comment: @MathDoctor: The statement that $T$ depends on $x$ just means that at each position $x$ there is a unique temperature. If $X$ is the set of all positions in the room, we can in principle imagine taking the temperature in degrees Celsius, say, at each position $x\in X$. Then we can define a function $f$ from $X$ to $\Bbb R$ by setting $$f(x)=\text{temperature at }x$$ for each $x\in X$. If we’re using a variable $T$ to represent temperature, we can of course then set $T=f(x)$, though in practice this is most useful when we actually know something about the function $f$, i.e., about how ...

Comment: ... the temperature changes as we change the position.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, Brian. That all makes sense, but I have one quick follow up question: why does the statement "$T$ depends on $x$" mean that at each position $x$ there is a *unique* temperature $T$? I'm sure it's right in front of me, I just can't seem to convince myself.

Comment: @MathDoctor: You’ve misplaced the emphasis: the point of my statement is that each position has its own temperature associated with it. Uniqueness is a matter of physical fact: a given point in the room has a unique temperature. Different points can have different temperatures, so what the temperature is depends on the point. I should add, however, that when we’re talking in a mathematical setting about two variables $T$ and $x$, the statement that $T$ depends on $x$ can almost always be understood simply as an idiomatic way of saying that $T$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Hi good afternoon, Brian. I've thinking about your previous comment and had one last question: I don't think I have used the word *idiomatic* like this before and wanted to make sure I understand. When you say "...the statement that $T$ depends on $x$ can almost always be understood simply as an *idiomatic* way of saying that $T$ is a function of $x$", does this mean that (when we're talking in a mathematical setting about two variables $T$ and $x$, of course) the statement "T depends on x" **means** "T is a function of x"?

Comment: @MathDoctor: Almost: one can also say that $T$ depends on $x$ when $T$ is a function of $x$ **and some other variables**, though in my experience it most often means simply that $T=f(x)$ for some function $f$.

Comment: Gotcha! So in most cases we can assume that “$T$ depends on $x$” means $T = f(x)$ for some function $f$? (Thank you for your patience and time also, Brian. Sorry for dragging this out!)

Comment: @MathDoctor: Yes, but bearing in mind the possibility that $T$ may depend on other variables as well; as a rule this will be very clear from the context. You’re welcome!